# Is there a way to trigger an event when an element is not visible?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am reaching out because I need to track when an overlay is not visible anymore so i can fire an event there.
Can I add an event listener when an element is no longer visible? Can I then make a trigger for this so an event can fire?

- I have tried the premade element visibility that GTM provides.
- I also tried to make a CJS for when it's visible

Edit:

- The only thing that changes is the visibility of the item, it doesn't change names or anything. The overlay become non visible when they click on the gateway payment method.

Comment: Is there any class or style will change in that element? But still lack of the timing of the event. Can you explain it more detail about if user performs anything will cause this element becoming not visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usecase is quite annoying to implement and the hack for it is not elegant. Therefore, my first move would be to persuade the developers to push a DL event on that element becoming not visible. They definitely making it invisible in a callback of some kind, so they can definitely push an event there, they wouldn't even need to deploy a listener.

If the devs don't want to, then I would try and push back with the data stakeholder who wants it. There's likely no business value in that tracking. Most of the tracking requests have little to no business value, and as such, they have to be dismissed.

Finally, if I really need to hack it with GTM. And it's a hack. Then I would have to deploy a setInterval function with a CHTML tag that would check your element's visibility and fire an event when it stops being visible. A trigger for it could be the visibility trigger, or something else. Again, it's a dirty temporary solution that I would hate to see in any GTM implementation. It's sloppy things like these that cause long-term GTM problems.

Comment: Would the code look something like this?`<script>
setInterval(function() {
  if (!checkVisibility()) {
    // element is not visible, fire event or do something else
    console.log('Element is not visible!');
  }
}, 1000); // check every second (1000ms)
</script>`

Comment: Yes, that looks about right.